# Can not connect to Amazon EC2 Window Instance?

Tags: amazon-ec2, remote-desktop

I was only provided an Amazon EC2 Window Instance: ec2-54-200-63-126.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com.

When I try to connect to it by using Remote Desktop Connection, it notifies me that:

Remote Desktop can't connect to the remote computer for one of these reasons:

1. Remote access to the server is not enabled
2. The remote computer is turned off
3. The remote computer is not available on the network

I had searched for an hour and I see that I have to configure something with this instance?
Is there any guide, blog, website for configuring a new instance to be connected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you configured a security group (basically a firewall) for the server that has the RDP port open?

Comment: That's reason. Our security team only open some common port.